# object has no attribute 'is_valid'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am receiving an error, object has no attribute 'is_valid', when trying to insert form data into a form. Below is the structure of my code:
model.py

[image]

view.py

[image]

index.html

[image]

Comment: Please share *code*, *not* images of code.

Answer (score 0):

`fm = Reg()` doesn't really make sense. You can't assign a model/instance to a variable and consider it a form. Instead, create a form based on your model like this:

Create a file `forms.py` and create a ModelForm in it:

```
    from django.forms import ModelForm
    from mysite.models import Reg

    class RegForm(ModelForm):
      class Meta:
         model = Reg
         fields = ('<field_names>',)
```

ModelForm let's you create a form based on your Model.

Now import this in your views.py and use RegForm instead of Reg.

Comment: after adding is going is_valid function its going else statement